# Still Image Video With AVFoundation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

It's my first time posting on this site, so I hope I didn't make a mistake...
I am currently developing a small app in Swift 2, and one of the functions is to append a still image video (a video clip that is only a particular image, with X duration), to another video.
  I have already obtained the video, the image, and everything, the problem is the next step...
I have experience with Swift and `UIKit`, but none with the `AVFoundation` Kit.
   Could someone point a way, example or guide to perform this task?  
Thanks in advance!